# How come certain parts of my model don't print?

Tags: elegoo-neptune-3

I use Elegoo Cura.

The blade and other parts of my print do not get sliced, and I don't know how to fix it

This is what is meant to be printed:

[image: This is what is meant to be printed]

And this is what the print looks like, with the holes inverted, handle gone and the entire blade gone:

[image: This is what the print looks like]

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Cura is terrible. The option "Print Thin Walls", which is disabled by default for some reason, should help though.

Comment: @towe no? that's inverted surface error

Answer (score 1):

The model has surfaces that are inverted. This is most notable with how the hole in the grip is turned into a cylinder, or the cutout in the blade being turned into a block.

To fix this, you need to fix the model.

Comment: I downloaded it from Cults3D and I have no idea how, I will try to find another model.

Answer (score 0):

Bad model, as Trish says. Now onto how to fix it.

Install [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) and open it.

[image: Screenshot of the Blender Preferences pane with Add-ons selected]

Go to **Edit** > **Preferences** > **Add-ons**.

Select the **Mesh: 3D Toolbox** plugin and install it.

Restart Blender.

[image: Screenshot of an import STL with the '3D Print' tab menu open]

Import your STL (**File** > **Import** > **STL**). Press <kbd>N</kbd> to bring up the sidebar if not already visible, find the **3D Print** tab and select it, and open the **Clean Up** subsection.
Select your model in the main view (left-click it so it has an orange outline) and click **Make Manifold**.

The process may take a while, and Blender will be unresponsive throughout. After it completes, you'll see a message on the bottom: "Modified:" and some numbers of elements fixed. Repeat **Make Manifold** until "Modified:" shows only zeros.

[image: Screenshot of the 'Modified:' message at the bottom of the window showing the number of repaired elements]

Make sure the repaired mesh is selected (orange outline). Pick **File** > **Export** > **STL**, and make sure you check **Selection only** then save the fixed mesh.

[image: Screenshot of the File Export dialog box with the 'Selection only' option selected]

As of now, this is the easiest, most comprehensive, and most successful auto-repair option for meshes. That's not to say it's extremely successful—if the mesh is a hot mess, it may not help, it may even make things worse. In that case, you're up for a manual repair—you may need to look into more advanced repair tips, like from CG Boost's YouTube video ["How to Solve Common Sculpting Problems in Blender"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DAdYQ4xpNo0&lc=UgyNDx-3-waxKw8RfkR4AaABAg).